# Why does Google say I need chrome to use my Yubico security key?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, yubico

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but here goes.
When I'm trying to sign into google, and it asks for my security key, it says that it can only be used in Chrome. This is a problem because my school only has internet explorer on the computers (bad, I know) and this makes it more annoying to sign in.
Is there a workaround, and does anyone know why this is?

(p.s. I have tried to find some info about this but nothing explains why it needs chrome, especially since when I trigger the key in microsoft word all it does it print some text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yubico Security Key is a very new technology. Microssoft will support Yubico Security in Windows 10. But Internet explorer was discontinued in January 21, 2015. So any of the new technologies released after that is not supported. I am afraid there is no work around at the moment.

So which browsers support U2F?

You must be running Google Chrome version 38 or later, or Opera version 40 or later. Both browsers include support for the U2F protocol.
Firefox Quantum now natively supports U2F.  FIDO U2F is not turned on by default in the Firefox browser.To see how to turn it on check the link1 below.

But there is a workaround. For now, you can use backup codes from Google Authenticator or Yubico Authenticator, for two-factor authentication if your browser doesn’t support U2F. **You need to install an Android application or Desktop which will generate an one time password for you to use in IE.** Check link2.

link1: https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000006417-getting-started-with-your-yubikey

link2: https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000006419

Comment: So its because IE dosen't support U2F?

Comment: Yes. Please check the updated answer.